# Existence of a minimizer for an optimization problem in $L^1 (0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization

Let $\theta \in L^\infty (0,1)$.

I want to prove the existence of a solution to the following problem:

> minimize:  $\int_0 ^1 e^{[v(t)-1]^2} dt$
>
> subject to:  $v \in L^1 (0,1)$, $\int_0 ^1 \theta(t)v(t)dt =0$.

I cannot proceed since AFAIK, there is no good compactness property for $L^1$ that can be exploited for this situation. (e.g. $L^1$ is not reflexive)

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am pretty sure that if the functional you want to minimize is finite, then actually $v \in L^p$ for all $p$. So you can just work with $L^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m=\inf \{\int_0^{1} e^{[v(t)-1]^{2}} dt: v \in L^{1}, \int v(t)\theta(t)dt=0\}$. There exist a sequence $(v_n)$ in $L^{1}$ such that $\int_0^{1} e^{[v_n(t)-1]^{2}} dt \to m$. Note that $[v_n(t)-1]^{2} \leq e^{[v_n(t)-1]^{2}} dt$. It follows that $(v_n)$ is bounded in $L^{2}(0,1)$. This implies that some subsequence $(v_{n_k})$ converges weakly, say to $v$. We have $\int v(t)\theta(t)dt=\lim \int v_n(t)\theta(t)dt=0$. Also Fatou's Lemma shows that $\int_0^{1} e^{[v(t)-1]^{2}} dt \leq \lim \inf \int_0^{1} e^{[v_n(t)-1]^{2}} dt=m$. Hence the minimum value $m$ is attained at the function $v$.

Note: 
The existence of a subnet of $(v_n)$ follows from reflexivity of $L^{2}$ but for the existence of  a subsequence we have to apply Dunford - Pettis Theorem.